# Alternatives to the case statement in mysql 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have the following two tables,

*Allowance* table,

```
employeeId    title    value       Salary   
  14          Mobile    200         13000    
  14          Transport 7000        13000
```

*Codes* table,

```
title               code
Transport            A1 
Mobile               A2 
Salary               A3
```

I want to get the result that looks like this,

```
employeeId    title       value    code     
      14       Mobile      200       A2          
      14       Transport   7000      A1     
      14        Salary     13000     A3
```

My query is as below,

```
select employeeId,title,CASE 
     WHEN title = 'Mobile'    THEN 'A1'
     WHEN title = 'Transport' THEN 'A2'
     ELSE 'A3' 
     END as AllowancesCode,
    value
     from Reports where employeeId = 14 ;
```

predictably this misses out on *Salary* field,

```
 employeeId title   AllowancesCode  value
   14       Mobile      A1           200
   14      Transport    A2          7000
```

**EDIT**

A bit more clarity on the data,

an employee could have different allowances with different values, but the salary is fixed and will only be one value. Another employee with another employeeid could have the same salary. One employeeId will be having one value for salary.

Comment: Imagine that Salary column values in 1st table are 12000 and 14000 - what is the output in this case?

Comment: @Akina the salary column value will be the same for an employee. employeeid field is the key here.

Comment: *the salary column value will be the same for an employee* Prove it - provide the constraint which provides this equiness. If it not exists then the values MAY DIFFER.

Comment: @Akina not sure how you want me to prove it but i know my data. Think of it this way, an employee could have different allowances with different values, but the salary is fixed and will only be one value. Another employee with another employeeid could have the same salary though. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: "predictably this misses out on Salary field," - what exactly does that mean? The expected result you've shared does not contain any "Salary field"

Comment: @NicoHaase it means the Salary field does not show in the query result

Comment: @Bisoux One minor database fail - and you may have non-detectable logical integrity error in your data. I'd recommend to remove Salary column but add a row with `Title = 'Salary'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to argue on the table structure, which probably is suboptimal.

I think you are better do a join for the "Mobile" and "Transport" and then do a second query with union for the salary.

The salary Value is it replicated on every row and is it the same?
Something like this should work

```
    SELECT A.employeeId, A.title, A.value, B.code 
        FROM Allowance A INNER JOIN Codes B ON (A.title=B.title)
        WHERE A.employeeId = 14 
    UNION
    SELECT A.employeeId," Salary" as title, max(A.basicSalary) as value, B.code
        FROM Allowance A INNER JOIN Codes B ON (B.title="basicSalary")
        WHERE A.employeeId = 14 
        GROUP BY 1,2,4
```

If you do not want to use 2 where and data is not too much you could create a view or simply do:

```
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT A.employeeId, A.title, A.value, B.code 
           FROM Allowance A INNER JOIN Codes B ON (A.title=B.title)
        UNION
        SELECT A.employeeId," Salary" as title, max(A.basicSalary) as value, B.code
           FROM Allowance A INNER JOIN Codes B ON (B.title="basicSalary")
           GROUP BY 1,2,4
    ) X
    WHERE X.employeeId=14
```

Comment: The salary would be unique for an employeeid

Comment: Thank you, I tweaked the first query and looks like it is working